# TypeError: GenericAlias expected 2 arguments, got 0 error

Tags: python, error-handling

I run a code but, it actually run @Python3.9 however, doesn't @python3.11
+

```
  dqs = dqsraw['1.14V'].str.extractall('(\*+)')[0].str.len().loc[lambda x: x > 20].groupby(level=0).agg(list[0]).str[1]  # ('match', fill_value=0)
```

I doubt the ver.of python... how can i solve this error..?

```
line 1948, in __call__return self.func(*args)

,line 280, func = maybe_mangle_lambdas(func)
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

   line 1536, in maybe_mangle_lambdas
  mangled_aggspec = type(agg_spec)()  # dict or OrderedDict
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```